# Setting http status but keep normal view?

Tags: ruby, hanami

How can I set different http status but keep normal view? Currently I have these two lines in my action

```
self.status = 403
self.body = Web::Views::Login::Form.render(exposures)
```

However my problems is that I get complete different page, just gray page with big rectangle in the middle with with HTML text of `self.body` (escaped, so I see the actual source code, not the page).

So, how can I set reponse code while keeping regular view processing (== displaying `self.body`)?

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in?  Some browsers will render alternate content depending on the response.  Hanami will likewise render its own views for non-success codes - https://github.com/hanami/hanami/blob/master/lib/hanami/views/default.rb#L10

Comment: @Joe so failed login should return 200? :-O that sounds... weird. The action (login attempt) obviously failed, so getting back 200 doesn't seem correct; anyway regardless of it being good idea or not, I'm still having hard time believing it's just not possible to do :/

Comment: Duh. I was reading question wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to do at the moment, see https://github.com/hanami/hanami/issues/874 for workaround.